# Certificate chain with different keysizes - validity check

Tags: cryptography

Is a certificate chain valid if its certificates have different keysizes i.e. a user certificate has keysize pair of 2048 bits and its CA certificate ahs keysize of 1024 bits or vice-versa.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is valid. The validation is only about if the user certificate has been signed by the CA certificate (and if the CA certificate have the proper extensions configured - not all libraries check this though).
The keysize is unrelated to the validation of the chain